# run commands on a split frame in the main window using tkinter

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, tkinter, pycharm

I'm new to tkinter and i've built this so far:

```
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess
import os


def maingui():

    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title("My first GUI")
    #window.state('zoomed')
    window.geometry("700x205")
    window.configure(bg="black")

    frame1 = tk.Frame(window, width=90, bg="orange")
    # frame1.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.LEFT)
    frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)

    frame2 = tk.Frame(window, width=1890, bg="black")
    # frame2.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.RIGHT)
    frame2.grid(row=0, column=1)

    lotomat = tk.Button(frame1, text="  Start\n   Lotomat", padx=10, pady=5, bg="orange", fg="black",
                        relief=tk.GROOVE, command=lambda : startLotomat())
    # lotomat.pack()
    lotomat.grid(row=1, column=0)

    convert = tk.Button(frame1, text="   URL2IP \n on \n   Desktop", padx=10, pady=5, bg="orange", fg="black",
                        relief=tk.GROOVE, command=lambda : startURL2IP())
    # convert.pack()
    convert.grid(row=2, column=0)

    startRps = tk.Button(frame1, text="    Start    \nR.P.S", padx=12, pady=5, bg="orange", fg="black",
                         relief=tk.GROOVE, command=lambda : startRPS())
    # startRps.pack()
    startRps.grid(row=3, column=0)

    endRun = tk.Button(frame1, text="Quit", padx=12, pady=10, bg="orange", fg="black",
                       relief=tk.RIDGE, command=lambda : ending())
    # endRun.pack()
    endRun.grid(row=4, column=0)

    def startLotomat():
        os.system('python lotomat.py')

    def startURL2IP():
        os.system('python urltoipondesktop.py')

    def startRPS():
        os.system('python rockpaperscissors.py')

    def ending():
        exit()

    window.mainloop()

maingui()
```

each button runs a different .py file.
how can I use frames to split the window so the program runs on the right side?
Thanks!

Edit:
I've added a pic of the GUI, the goal is to run the left menu buttons on the black frame.
[image]

Comment: Could you please post all the `.py` files? Thanks!

Comment: how are they relevant? they work inside the env (Pycharm)

Comment: Ok then, but I don't have pycharm, and you should put that tag.

Comment: tags updated, thx for the comment

Comment: Are the 3 scripts tkinter applications as well?

Comment: no, terminal only.

Comment: So do you mean that you want to capture the console output of the scripts in the GUI?

Comment: exactly! by using frames.

Comment: Then take a look on [subprocess.run()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run).

Comment: This can be done with frames as well. no need to make it harder.

Comment: If you just want to capture the console output, better use `Text` widget instead of `Frame`.  Replace `os.system(...)` by `proc = subprocess.run(..., capture_output=True)`, then put the console output into the `Text` widget using `textbox.insert(tk.END, proc.stdout.decode())` where `textbox` is an instance of `Text`.

Comment: can you show me an example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214928/discussion-between-gilush-and-acw1668).

Answer (score 0):

Following acw1668's comment and alot of thread researching here's the thread solution. so elegant, so simple! I love python!

```
def thread_handler(self, host):

    wt = threading.Thread(target=self.write_to_file, args=(host,))
    pt = threading.Thread(target=self.print_to_box, args=(host,))
    dt = threading.Thread(target=self.delete_default_lines, args=())

    wt.start()
    pt.start()
    dt.start()
```